# How to chain caching - Cache your assets set by set according to their priority in javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, async-await, promise, browser-cache

For simplicity, let's say a given web app is using some files that exist in the root directory like,
*First set*: `image1.jpg` `info1.txt` `video1.mp4` and
*Second set*: `image2.jpg` `info2.txt` `video2.mp4` as well as
*Third set*: `image3.jpg` `info3.txt` `video3.mp4`

In this case «due to priority reasons» we would like these to be cached set by set in order. That means, the caching of the ***second*** group of files will start only after the ***first*** set is «hopefully» done caching, then ***third*** will start after ***second*** is finished etc.

Once we are good to go with,

```
if ('caches' in window){
    // Safe to try
}
```

we want to use
`const myCache1 = await caches.open('my-cache-1');`
`const myCache2 = await caches.open('my-cache-2');`
`const myCache3 = await caches.open('my-cache-3');`
to create the cache containers (like folders hidden inside the browser),
and then we can

```
const firstGroup = ['/image1.jpg', '/info1.txt', '/video1.mp4'];
const secondGroup = ['/image2.jpg', '/info2.txt', '/video2.mp4'];
const thirdGroup = ['/image3.jpg', '/info3.txt', '/video3.mp4'];
```

but now we want to chain `myCache1.addAll(firstGroup);` `myCache2.addAll(secondGroup);` `myCache3.addAll(thirdGroup);`
so that files get downloaded depending on their importance (or whatever logical reason to put things in order).

Note1: The `.then().catch().finally()` chaining is essential but `async/await` answers are also welcome.
Note2: Inclusion of error handling in case of flaky internet connection would be nice but not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all you need to do is call the `addAll`s in order with async/await, like so:

```js
async function loadFiles () {
  const myCache1 = await caches.open('my-cache-1');
  const myCache2 = await caches.open('my-cache-2');
  const myCache3 = await caches.open('my-cache-3');
  const firstGroup = ['/image1.jpg', '/info1.txt', '/video1.mp4'];
  const secondGroup = ['/image2.jpg', '/info2.txt', '/video2.mp4'];
  const thirdGroup = ['/image3.jpg', '/info3.txt', '/video3.mp4'];

  try {
    // load group 1 first
    await myCache1.addAll(firstGroup);
    // then load group 2
    await myCache2.addAll(secondGroup);
    // then load group 3
    await myCache3.addAll(thirdGroup);
  } catch(err) {
    // error handling goes here
    console.error(err);
  }
}
loadFiles();
```

Comment: Looks like one neat way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Now, I wonder what happens with a page refresh as loadFiles() is called one more time. Would it be good practice to prevent a second call to loadFiles()? Or is it totally unnecessary because the way the browser handles things is nice enough?

Comment: @HolyResistance That's the whole point of a cache. It will load assets from memory rather than fetching them each time. Assuming you're not doing anything for cache-busting

Comment: Sure. It would probably take less than a negligible millisecond to go through the list if it's a static cache. For other situations however here is a tool that can be useful:  https://www.talater.com/adderall/

Comment: @HolyResistance Did my answer resolve your question? I want to make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: Yes. With extra thanks for your extra concern!

Comment: Would you be interested in taking a look at another interesting question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915595/clarification-needed-about-using-relative-file-paths-with-the-cache-api-compar